# what is the probability that is real numbers (2015 AMC.12)

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

I have end this eaxm,and I can't solve this problem

Rational numbers $a$ and $b$ are chosen at random among all rational numbers in the interval $[0,2)$ that can be written as fractions $\tfrac nd$ where $n$ and $d$ are integers with $1\leq d\leq 5$.  What is the probability that $$(\cos(a\pi)+i\sin(b\pi))^4$$ is a real number?

$\textbf{(A) }\dfrac3{50}\qquad\textbf{(B) }\dfrac4{25}\qquad\textbf{(C) }\dfrac{41}{200}\qquad\textbf{(D) }\dfrac6{25}\qquad\textbf{(E) }\dfrac{13}{50}$

This problem is  2015 AMC 12A #24

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3734494&sid=82090b270e6e861262faffa19ce3aba4#p3734494

Comment: (1) What are the rational numbers you can pick from? (2) What has to be true of $a$ and/or $b$ for the expression to be real? (3) Which values among the listed rationals satisfy the condition you need? (4) What fraction of the listed numbers does this give?

Comment: Hint (similar to the previous one by the way, just a different presentation): You have a condition on $d$, and a condition on $\frac nd$, so you have also a condition on $n$. Furthermore, you have a very limited set of possible rational numbers...

Comment: Did you even do $(\alpha +i\beta)^4$ to see the conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was asked a while ago but I think I can offer a very detailed solution.

This idea of this problem is pretty straightforward: find the imaginary part of the expansion and set it to $0$. Find all $(a,b)$ that satisfy this, and divide by the total number of possibilities of $(a,b)$.

First note that there are $20$ choices for $a,b$ (this can be seen by simply listing out all possible rationals and eliminating the repeated ones). Thus there are $20\cdot 20=400$ total possibilities.

Now note that $$\Im((\cos(a\pi)+i\sin(b\pi))^4)=4\cos(a\pi)^3\sin(b\pi)-4\cos(a\pi)\sin(b\pi)^3=4\cos(a\pi)\sin(b\pi)(\cos^2(a\pi)-\sin^2(b\pi))$$

Setting this equal to $0$, we have the folllowing $2$ cases:

**Case 1**: One of the first two terms is equal to $0$, or equivalently, $a\in\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\}$ or $b\in\{0,1\}$. There are $2\cdot 2\cdot 20-2\cdot 2=76$ possibilities in this case (where we subtract off the overcounted pairs where both $a$ and $b$ are equal to their respective values).

**Case 2**: The last term is equal to $0$. One can observe that this only occurs at $\cos a\pi= \sin b\pi= \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm1 $. Equivalently, $a,b\in\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4}\}$ or $a\in\{0,1\}$ and $b\in\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\}$. This case gives $4\cdot 4+2\cdot 2=20$ choices.

Adding the two, we have a total of $96$ choices, so the desired answer is $\frac{96}{400}=\frac{6}{25}$